# Laravel Intervention Image not working

Tags: php, laravel

I installed Laravel [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation) class by composer, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374613/laravel-intervention-image-class-class-not-found/27504070#27504070) tutorial, And when I type composer update, composer returns:

```
D:\WEB\htdocs\zanbil>composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing intervention/image (dev-master b91b0d6)
    Downloading: 100%
    Downloading: 100%

intervention/image suggests installing intervention/imagecache (Caching extension for the Intervention Image library)
intervention/image suggests installing ext-imagick (to use Imagick based image processing.)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Generating optimized class loader
```

And this is what I am going to use with **Intervention Image**:

```
$image=Input::file('image');
        $name = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        var_dump(Image::make($image->getRealPath()->resize('280','280')->save('public/up/city/'.$name)));
```

And when I run that code Laravel return (with browser):

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Call to a member function resize() on a non-object

### What is the Problem?

Comment: You call `resize` on the result of `getRealPath()`. I think you want to do something like this instead: `Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize('280', '280')->save('public/up/city/'.$name)`

Comment: You're welcome. I voted to close since it's just a typo and it's unlikely it will help someone else in the future.

Comment: @lukasgeiter Somehow your solution not working for me as it says: *Image source not readable*

Comment: @Volatil3 Then your problem is probably unrelated to this post. Please ask a new question.

Comment: @lukasgeiter Ok done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747580/intervention-not-resizing-large-files

Answer (score 3):

You call *resize* on the result of **getRealPath()**. I think you want to do something like this instead:

```
Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize('280', '280')->save('public/up/city/'.$name)
```

Thanks [lukasgeiter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1903366/lukasgeiter) for Answer