# Intervention not resizing large files

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using `[Intervention][1]` to resize Files. I figured out it is not resizing large files like [this one](http://intuitiontosucceed.academy/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/K2_Mount_Godwin_Austen_Chogori_Savage_Mountain1.jpg)

Code I am using is:

```
if (Input::hasFile('image'))
            {
                $file = Input::file('image');
                $r = $file->move('uploads', $file->getClientOriginalName());
                Image::make('/mountain.jpg')->resize(200,200)->save('uploads/k2.jpg');
                //print_r($image);
                exit;
            }
```

Code works fine for smaller files. The file size is 2.x MB and my PHP limit is 32MB.

**Update**: Laravel Log says:

```
' with message 'Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3008 bytes`
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Atleast not in application level. Should I check log?

Comment: @MattBurrow Yes I find this: `' with message 'Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3008 bytes`

Comment: Increase your `memory_limit` value within your php.ini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through finding out your error log message; `Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3008 bytes`, your app is running out of memory.

Increase this by changing the value of `memory_limit` within your php.ini file.

Be sure to restart your webserver.