# Laravel Class 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, image, laravel

this question is asked many times and I did all the introductions I could found but I still get this error message.

I updated my config/app.php (

providers:

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
```

aliases:

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,
```

and the composer.json

```
"intervention/image": "dev-master",
```

After this I did a composer update but my error message is still the same.. I'm using laravel 5

I did what the link says:

http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation

and yeah.. now I'm stuck

Another thing I dont understand is why they say I should write:

```
'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider'
```

in the provider array. Why the ' '? All the other elements in my provider array are written like this:

```
'Request'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
'Response'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
'Route'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
```

so I removed the ' ' and addet ::class

the same with the aliases

I dont know if thats okay but maybe someone of you could help me

thanks for help

Comment: If I understood it right then I think it is similar with an issue I had.. Try using an alias as `Img` instead of `Image`. It seems that there is a conflict with another framework class

Comment: I did that but this havent changed anything :/

Comment: check your vendor folder and make sure the class actually exists.

Comment: Have you tryed composer update and php artisan dump-autoload?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel / Intervention Image Class - class not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374613/laravel-intervention-image-class-class-not-found)

Comment: well I made it somehow.. but not I get this error: Image source not readable -- do you know what I can do against it?

Answer (score 0):

The `::class` operator gives the fully qualified class name and was introduced in PHP 5.5 as you can see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class). It's perfectly ok to use it if you have PHP >= 5.5.

I would suggest to check in the vendor directory if the package exists. I use `"intervention/image": "^2.3"` and everything's working great on L5.1

Comment: Try to put `"intervention/image": "^2.3"` in your composer.json, then delete composer.lock and the entire vendor directory. Then do `composer install`

Comment: I did, but still the same

Comment: So Laravel just crashes at startup? You don't even reference the facade or class anywhere except in the config/app.php file?

Comment: well its like I said in my question :o

Comment: well I made it somehow.. but not I get this error: Image source not readable -- do you know what I can do against it?

Comment: How did you solved the first problem? Maybe the extension or format is not supported Intervention Image?