# Laravel 5.2: Class 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, homestead, intervention

I am trying to integrate Intervention Image into my project. I have followed the guide, used a shitton of other tutorials and no matter what I do, I keep getting the same error:

```
Class 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider' not found
```

It is included in my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/envoy": "~1.0",
        "laravel/installer": "^1.3",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3"
    }
}
```

I have installed the php-gd thingy, I included

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
```

and

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

in my `config\app.php`, but I keep getting the annoying error message. 
Maybe it's worth mentioning that I am on a Linux Mint OS and that I am using the Homestead Virtual Machine. Yes, I included the thingies in the Homestead version of Composer, not on my main PC's composer. When using

```
PHP artisan --version
```

, it returns:

```
Laravel Framework version 5.2.43
```

I ran composer update on the Virtual Machine, didn't solve the problem. I tried removing the lines from `app.php`, running composer update, adding the lines again and running composer update, didn't work.

Does it matter where I have the inclusions in `config\app.php`? Right now, the alias is in the list and the provider is under Package Service Providers.

Here is the full error message:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
FatalThrowableError in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider' not found
in ProviderRepository.php line 146
at ProviderRepository->createProvider('Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider') in ProviderRepository.php line 114
at ProviderRepository->compileManifest(array('Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider', 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider')) in ProviderRepository.php line 60
at ProviderRepository->load(array('Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider', 'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider', 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider', 'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider')) in Application.php line 530
at Application->registerConfiguredProviders() in RegisterProviders.php line 17
at RegisterProviders->bootstrap(object(Application)) in Application.php line 203
at Application->bootstrapWith(array('Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\DetectEnvironment', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders')) in Kernel.php line 232
at Kernel->bootstrap() in Kernel.php line 127
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Comment: Have you run `composer update`?

Comment: Yes, several times, I'll add it to the info.

Comment: have you followed the guide line here http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation just to be sure

Comment: Yeahp, I followed that guide line to line all the way through.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your Use statement, where you are using the class, has the correct namespace?

Comment: Check This [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374613/laravel-intervention-image-class-class-not-found ) for reference your issue

Comment: Thanks, but I've already seen that question and did everything they mentioned there.

Comment: @RogerCreasy: I am not even using it yet, just added it to the `config\app.php` file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, it turns out i wasn't running this command `$ php composer.phar require intervention/image` on the root of my project. I did ran it on the root of my project and everything was fine.

E.g
`Itses-MacBook-Pro:testproject bigtank$ composer require intervention/image`

run it like this and it would work.

Cheers.

Comment: running composer require intervention/image worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Remove facade and service provider from `config/app.php`, then run `composer dumpauto` (if it will not help, run `composer dumpauto -o`). After that add facade and service provider back to `config/app.php`.

Comment: Did it with `composer dumpauto`, terminal said "Generating autoload files", after reloading webpage error still exists.. `composer dumpauto -o`, terminal outputs "Generating optimized autoload files", again no effect on the error.

Comment: Try to manually delete all `php` files in `bootstrap/cache` directory and run `composer dumpauto` again.

Comment: Deleted the `php` file in `bootstrap/cache`, error still pops up.

Comment: Ok, did you get any errors during package installation? Do you have `\vendor\intervention\image\src\Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider.php` file in project directory?

Comment: No errors during install, but it seems I don have `\vendor\intervention\`.

Comment: Ok. Remove facade and service provider from config again and run `composer require intervention/image`. This should install intervention (loot at errors and messages). After that run `composer dumpauto -o` and add service provider and facade to the config again.

Comment: Terminal after `composer require intervention/image`:
`Using version ^2.3 for intervention/image
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files`

Did the `composer dumpauto -o`, added the lines in `config\app.php`. Still the same error. Files are still missing from `vendor`.

Comment: Then you'll need to remove it from `composer.json` and run `composer update` to unistall it first. And install it like I described in my previous comment.

Comment: DId everything, still no folder in my `vendor` .. Does this mean I screwed up somewhere else? I'm not super great with Linux. I'm doing all of these commands in the `~\.composer\` folder of my VM, not in my laravel folder, is that correct?

Comment: You get `Nothing to install or update` again? Are you sure you deleted intervention from `composer.json` and ran `composer update`? If yes, what message(s) did you get (it should tell you intervention package was removed or something like that). Also, try to delete `composer.lock` file. Double check everything again.

Comment: `  - Removing intervention/image (2.3.7)` is what it said (among with the usual lines) after I edited the `.json` and ran `composer update`. When I ran `composer require intervention/image`, it said `  - Installing intervention/image (2.3.7)
    Loading from cache

intervention/image suggests installing ext-imagick (to use Imagick based image processing.)
intervention/image suggests installing intervention/imagecache (Caching extension for the Intervention Image library)` among with the usual stuff. Deleting `composer.lock` and running `composer update` had no effect either.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you followed the installation guide carefully.

You need to first run:

`composer require intervention/image`

and you should modify config.app.php after you already install this package (so after
run `composer require`) and not before.

Comment: What should i modify in config/app.php?

Answer (score 0):

After many hours, various attempts and following all of the advice that keeps getting repeated on this one: I solved it by downgrading to v2. Then it worked on the first try.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same class not found problem on Laravel 9.52 version and solved it by following this link and downgrading to V2 is not a good idea.

https://image.intervention.io/v3/introduction/frameworks