# intervention/image NOT FOUND

Tags: php, laravel

Iam trying to  install `intervention/image` package for that I follow steps from
[laravel-intervention-image-class-class-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374613/laravel-intervention-image-class-class-not-found)
but i got error when i update composer

Problem 1

> laravel/framework v5.1.9 requires symfony/css-selector 2.7.* -> satisfiable by symfony/css-selector[2.7.x-dev, v2.7.0, v2.7.0-BETA1,
>   v2.7.0-BETA2, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14,
>   v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21,
>   v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28,
>   v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7,
>   v2.7.8, v2.7.9] but these conflict with your requirements or
>   minimum-stability.

Comment: run `composer update` before install the intervention

Comment: remove intervention/image from your composer, then run ```composer update``` and reinstall it

Comment: how i will install intervention/image

Answer (score 2):

To install the most recent version, run the following command.

```
composer require intervention/image
```

After you have installed Intervention Image, open your Laravel config file config/app.php and add the following lines.

In the $providers array add the service providers for this package.

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
```

Add the facade of this package to the $aliases array.

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
```

And you are ready to go.